# "and" to "und" when I cite two authors

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change the English "and" to the German "und" when I cite two authors with /parencite. I'm using Bibdesk for my bibliography.

```
\usepackage{acronym}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\addbibresource{refrences3.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

If I use \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}, I get the following errors:

```
./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@nonfrenchspacing ->\sfcode `\.3000\sfcode `\?
                                                  3000\sfcode `\!3000\sfcode...
l.60 \begin{document}

./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ->\iffieldundef 
                               {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield ...
l.60 \begin{document}

./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ...f {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring 
                                                  {from\thefield {origlangua...
l.60 \begin{document}

./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@lfromlang ...} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield 
                                                  {origlanguage}}\space }
l.60 \begin{document}

./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@sfromlang ->\iffieldundef 
                               {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring {from\thefield ...
l.60 \begin{document}

./Introduction.tex:60: Undefined control sequence.
\lbx@sfromlang ...f {origlanguage} {} {\bibstring 
                                                  {from\thefield {origlangua...
l.60 \begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` ?

Comment: This would work but i get a lot of Errors

Comment: Remove the quite old `\usepackage{german}` and use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` (or for old orthography rules `\usepackage[german]{babel}`). You will have to remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) before re-compiling.

Comment: Kick out package `german`, trash all the auxiliary files and start compiling again.

Comment: If you still get the error after removing `\usepackage{german}` and clearing auxiliary files, please prepare a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: @TomBombadil Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @moewe: Sure, just give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the package `german` use `babel` with the appropriate language as a package option, `ngerman` in your case (unless you want the "alte deutsche Rechtschreibung", in which case it would be `german`). You can also supply more than one language, where the last langauge will be the main one: `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` means that your document uses english and german, with german being the main language.

`babel` will also localize the captions of lists of floats, the table of contents, in float captions and others. If you don't like the standard values, here are the most common redefinitions when you use a `Koma` documentclass:

```
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listtablename}{Tabellen}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}
```

or if you don't:

```
\addto{\captionsngerman}%
{ \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
  \renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}
  \renewcommand*{\listtablename}{Tabellen}
  \renewcommand*{\figurename}{Abb.}
  \renewcommand*{\tablename}{Tab.}
}
```